# How to retrieve a JavaScript property that contains a period

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am using the github API to get my gists. 
[The actual json returned from github](https://api.github.com/gists/1265374) contains a property called 'GetGists.js', how do I get the value of that property?

`gistObject.files.GetGists.js` returns an error

[This is my example](http://jsfiddle.net/guanome/udWgC/) page, when you click on the link it will log the object in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gistObject.files["GetGists.js"]` should be used. All JavaScript properties can also be accessed through square braces.

Another example:
    `window.location.href === window["location"].href == window["location"]["href"];`

Answer (score 2):

```
gistObject.files['GetGists.js']
```

Answer (score 2):

here's the solution

```
gistObject.files['GetGists.js']
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using dot notation, use index notation:

```
gistObject.files["GetGists.js"]
```